# Qt under MacOS scroll does not work properly

Tags: c++, qt

in my Qt applications (Qt 5.7, MacOS 10.12 Sierra), the mouse wheel scroll is producing erroneous values. I am catching `QMouseWheelEvent`s in an overload of a `wheelEvent(QMouseWheelEvent*)` of a QWidget:

```
void MyWidget::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event) {
  int deltaY = event->pixelDelta().y();
  printf("Delta %d\n", delta);
}
```

Most of the time, delta is 0, if I scroll a single mouse wheel step. Only if I scroll several steps, I get delta != 0. Why could this be happening?

Comment: "This function has been deprecated, use pixelDelta() or angleDelta() instead."

Comment: @E4z9 Sorry, I forgot to mention I already tested `pixelDelta().y()` and the result is the same

Comment: Dunno if this is the same problem you are seeing, but I've noticed that when using a "Magic Mouse" the wheelEvent() behavior is different; rather than getting fewer events with delta()=(+/- 120), I get many events with much smaller delta() values.  (I believe that difference is due to the magic mouse wheel's smooth/non-"clicky" turning behavior)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner yes it might be something like that, but I'm getting lots of deltas of 0

Comment: @manatttta Try angleDelta() rather than pixelDelta(), and see what you get.  It could be that values of less than one pixel are being rounded down to zero.